# Quasar - get API key from .env into boot files

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, dotenv

Get the value of `GOOGLE_MAP_API` variable in `.env` file into `gmap-vue.js` inside `boot/` directory

it's working if I use the ***key*** right away like this

```
  load: {
    key: 'AIzaSyCw9Txxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    ...
  }
```

but I would like to use the ***key*** coming from `.env` file like this `process.env.GOOGLE_MAP_API`

***quasar.conf.js***

```
module.exports = function (/* ctx */) {
  return {
    ...
    boot: [
      'gmap-vue'
    ],
```

***boot/gmap-vue.js***

```
import Vue from "vue";
import * as GmapVue from "gmap-vue";

Vue.use(GmapVue, {
  load: {
    key: process.env.GOOGLE_MAP_API,
    ...
  }
}
```

***.env***

```
GOOGLE_MAP_API='AIzaSyCw9Txxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

it will return an error:

```
Google Maps JavaScript API warning: InvalidKey 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#invalid-key
```

to summarize if I get the ***key*** from `process.env` it gives error

Comment: Did you try removing quotes in .env file?

Comment: yes I've tried that also

Comment: If you put somewhere in your component console.log(process.env.GOOGLE_MAP_API) do you get correct value?

Comment: yes, it's weird even when I remove double quote on string in `.env`(restart the terminal), when I console.log() it always adds double quote.

Comment: Perhaps you have different .env files? And you are modifying the wrong one?

Comment: currently the app only have one. `.env` file inside it is just one variable (GOOGLE_MAP_API)

Answer (score 2):

I've notice that when I access a **String** value from `process.env` it always adds double quotes (").

even if there's **No double quotes** of the string value from `.env`

so what I did is I use regex;

```
  load: {
    key: process.env.GOOGLE_MAP_API.replace(/"/g, ""),
```

EDIT: if you guys have better answer please give, thanks

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling onto this more recently, there are apparently a couple ways to get environment variables into your app/boot files:

**Method 1**

Per the latest [Quasar docs](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/handling-process-env) on environment variables, you can leverage the dotenv library to parse and inject your .env variables into the `env` object mounted in quasar.config.js:

```
build: {
  env: require('dotenv').config().parsed
}
```

Now, everything in your .env file will be available in the process.env object everywhere in your app files (boot, components, modules, etc)

**Method 2**

If you use Vite - I found this explanation on [Jason Watmore's Blog](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2022/05/28/vue-3-vite-access-environment-variables-from-dotenv-env). Basically anything you prefix with VITE_ in your .env files is available on the `import.meta.env` object.